# Impossible to change font of cell.textLabel in ios8

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uifont, ios8

I'm not able to change the textLabel's font in `UITableViewCell`. This line doesn't work with iOS 8 SDK : `[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16.5]];`

Can anyone give help me ?

EDIT : My app run with iOS7. I want to test it with iOS8. Only this line of code doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: please do autoresizeing uncheck in your nib file

Comment: that won't work as it's Obj-C syntax. Look at the swift guide on Devleoper site. iOS 8 is still under NDA

Comment: @Jeff They was no error. The simulator doesn't take this line in account.

Comment: @Rohit I don't use nib file.

Comment: @CW0007007 My app is totally written in Obj-C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the solution. This line:

`[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16.5]];`

change to this line :

`[[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 16.5]];`

This is the only change I made in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with xCode6, but you should check if the file is set to objective-c.

Comment: Yes, it is. "Default - Objective-C Sources"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it.
try opening your ttf file in the font book application and validate it. if you get a red X in one of the validation steps that might be the issue.
I replaced the ttf with a file from a different font and the problem was resolved.